# perl eval without block

Tags: perl, eval

I am learning perl eval. I understand how to use eval BLOCK, but I have came across the code below. What is the code below doing?

```
while(<>) {
    eval; 
    warn $@ if $@;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(<>) {
```

This reads input, and places it in the variable `$_`. The input used by `<>` is first `@ARGV` (if you called your script with arguments), then STDIN (standard input).

Information on the diamond operator [here](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node68.html).

```
eval;
```

This evaluates the line that was read, since not specifying what to evaluate looks at `$_`.

```
warn $@ if $@;
```

This line will display the warnings that appear in `$@`, if there are any.

Comment: So it means that it will evaluates lines of string from $_ from <> as perl statement?

Comment: It evaluates each line in turn. So for example, if the input contained `if (1) {` on the first line, then `print "ok";` on the second line, and `}` on the third line, these would each fail to evaluate. (Though, as ever, Perl's notion of what is considered to be a "line" when reading a file is [configurable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24RS).)

Answer (score 0):

Perl's `eval()` builtin can take either a BLOCK or an EXPR. If it is given an EXPR that EXPR will be evaluated as a string which contains Perl code to be executed.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

eval { say "Hello, Block World!"; };

eval 'say "Hello, String World!";';
```

This code executes both `say()`s as you would expect.

```
$ ./evals.pl
Hello, Block World!
Hello, String World!
```

In general the string version of `eval()` is considered dangerous, especially if you allow interpolation into that string based on variables that are coming from outside your control. For exmaple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $name = $ARGV[0] // 'World';

eval "say 'Hello, $name';";
```

This code is safe if called as so:

```
$ ./evals.pl Kaoru
Hello, Alex

$ ./evals.pl
Hello, World
```

But would be very dangerous if the user called it as:

```
$ ./evals.pl "Kaoru'; system 'rm -rf /"
```

On the other hand, in string `eval()`'s favour, it can be very useful as the opposite of `Data::Dumper::Dumper()` for turning dumped Perl code back into Perl-internal data structures. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $hashref = { a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 };

print Dumper $hashref;

my $VAR1;
my $hashref_copy = eval Dumper $hashref;

say $hashref_copy->{b};
```

Which, as you would expect, outputs:

```
$ ./evals.pl
$VAR1 = {
        'c' => 3,
        'b' => 2,
        'a' => 1
        };
2
```

See `perldoc -f eval` or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html for more details.

As of Perl 5.16.3, there is also an `evalbytes()` which treats the string as a byte string rather than a character string. See `perldoc -f perlunicode` or http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html for more details on the difference between character strings and byte strings.

The code which you asked about explicitly:

```
while(<>) {
    eval; 
    warn $@ if $@;
}
```

Is reading in each line of either `STDIN` or the files specified in @ARGV, and evaluating each line of input as a line of Perl code. If that Perl code fails to compile, or throws an exception via `die()`, the error is warned to `STDERR`. `perldoc -f eval` has the full details of how and why `eval()` might set `$@`.

As an example of the code being called:

```
$ echo 'print "foo\\n";' | ./evals.pl 
foo

$ echo 'print 1 + 1, "\\n";' | ./evals.pl
2

$ echo 'dfsdfsdaf' | ./evals.pl
Bareword "dfsdfsdaf" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1, <> line 1.

$ echo 'die "dead";' | ./evals.pl 
dead at (eval 1) line 1, <> line 1.
```